# How to put string from function as an argument for sqlite3.connect() in python

Tags: python, function, sqlite, tkinter

I have option menu widget:

```
optionTuple = ("filename1", "filename2", "filename3")
```

filename1, filename2, filename3 are also names of files in directory

then I have button which inter alia gets selected option value:

```
def btnConvertClick(self):
    filename = '"'+ optionMenuWidget.cget('text')+'"'
```

then I try to open [sqlite3]database file [filename1 or filename2 or filename3] according to selected option

```
selected_file = filename
db = sqlite3.connect(selected_file)
```

but I get error:

```
<class 'sqlite3.OperationalError'>: unable to open database file
```

I have no problem with:

```
db = sqlite3.connect("filename1")
```

Is it possible to put string from function [as above] as filename argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the filename without the quotes:

```
filename = optionMenuWidget.cget
```